# go map key by reference, comparison by dereference

Tags: go

I need to use large maps with large strings as keys. Is there a way in go's default `map` to specify the comparison test so that the key is treated as an address? If not, are there good libraries that implement this?

Note that what I want to prevent is long strings constantly being passed by copy whenever a map lookup is made.

Comment: A string isn't passed by copy, always by a "reference" whose size is independent of the size of the string. Note also that string comparison starts by checking if the two strings have the same address.

Comment: how about in the general case. say I have a custom BigFloat class that I want to hash.

Comment: Premature optimization...

Comment: You can't specify the test or the hash function, but you *can* use addresses as keys themselves if that's what you want (http://play.golang.org/p/4kYzKFoqZn) and as dystroy says strings and some other types like interface values are internally little structures holding references to the bulky data.

Comment: And, yeah, as Volker says make sure it's a problem before spending too much effort on solving it. :)

Comment: The addresses won't necessarily be always the same, in that case it probably wouldn't be necessary to use a map. Volker may have a point, but I like to have a clear idea of my design from the start.

Comment: For custom structs, the [comparison rules](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) apply. If your struct contains pointers that may not be the same for objects that you consider equivalent, comparison may not do what you want ([example](http://play.golang.org/p/6Gi7GvjKiQ)). If your struct contains a slice, Go doesn't define it as comparable and therefore won't use it as a map key. Fair to say Go maps are less flexible about key types than, say, STL maps or Python dicts.

Comment: Since the original question seems more or less answered by all these comments together, posted a summary as a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the particular case of strings, Go does what you want by default: [strings are currently represented by pointer/length pairs](http://research.swtch.com/godata) so you're not copying string data around when you copy strings.

In general, you can't specify a custom comparison (or hash) function. Other types and custom structs [are treated according to rules listed in the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators): pointers are compared by address, for example, fixed-size arrays are compared by value, and slice types aren't comparable in general so struct types that include them aren't usable as map key types.